# How to increase the frame rate of live streaming of image prediction in flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask, machine-learning, image-processing

I am working on a project where i have to translate sign language to english.I have developed the required model and also developed application using opencv. Here i take the frames from `videOCapture()` and predict it and display the sign .

Now i want to develop a web application for it ,  using flask.

My app.py is as follows.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import Video
sequence = ''
app=Flask(__name__)

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame,sequence=camera.get_frame()
        sequence = sequence.upper()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type:  image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame  + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video')

def video():
    return Response(gen(Video()),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame') 
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html' , sequence = sequence)
app.run(debug=True)
```

and my index.html is as follows

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}{% block content %}

<h1 style="text-align: center;">ASL Sign Detection</h1>
<div>
    <h1>Sentence::</h1>
    <h2 id = "seq" style="text-align: center;">{{ sequence }}</h2>
</div>
<br>
<div style="justify-content: center; display: flex; margin-top: 30px;">
    <img src="{{ url_for('video') }}">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Camera.py is as follows

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Disable tensorflow compilation warnings
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='3'
import tensorflow as tf


class Video(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.model()
    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()
    def model(self):
        self.label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile("logs/trained_labels.txt")]
        # Unpersists graph from file
        with tf.compat.v1.gfile.FastGFile("logs/trained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            _ = tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as self.sess:
            self.softmax_tensor = self.sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        self.c= 0
        self.res, self.score= '', 0.0
        self.i = 0
        self.mem = ''
        self.consecutive = 0
        self.sequence = ''
    def predict(self,image_data):
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            predictions = sess.run(self.softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
            # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
            top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

            max_score = 0.0
            res = ''
            for i in top_k:
                sign = self.label_lines[i]
                score = predictions[0][i]
                if score > max_score:
                    max_score = score
                    res = sign
            return res, max_score
    def get_frame(self):
        ret,frame=self.video.read()
        img = cv2.flip(frame, 1)    
        if ret:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = 200, 100, 400, 300
            img_cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            self.c+= 1
            image_data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img_cropped)[1].tostring() 
            if self.i == 4:
                res_tmp, self.score= self.predict(image_data)
                self.res= res_tmp
                self.i = 0
                if self.mem == self.res:
                    self.consecutive += 1
                else:
                    self.consecutive = 0
                if self.consecutive == 2 and self.res not in ['nothing']:
                    if self.res== 'space':
                        self.sequence += ' '
                    elif self.res== 'del':
                        self.sequence = self.sequence[:-1]
                    else:
                        self.sequence += self.res
                    self.consecutive = 0
            self.i += 1
            cv2.putText(img, '%s' % (self.res.upper()), (250,400), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255,255,255), 4)
            cv2.putText(img, '%.3f' % (float(self.score)), (200,450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255))
            self.mem = self.res
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (18,31,150), 3)

        ret,jpg=cv2.imencode('.jpg',img)
        return jpg.tobytes(),self.sequence.upper()
```

The process flow will be like:

This camera.py takes images from webcam predicts it and send the image and its corresponding string to app.py
From app.py using flask i should render it to html page
But this process is happening very slow.
The frame rate is too slow.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7PYn.png) looks like this.
The frames are being updated very slowly.

How do i increase the frame rate?

Comment: determine *where* the time is consumed. use a profiler, alternatively take time differences using `time.perf_counter()` around several pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your frame rate must be low because it is taking time to make predictions, convert your tensorflow model to [tflite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/index) for faster inference.